# Installing Docker on RedHat fails with 403 forbidden

Tags: rhel, docker

I'm trying to install Docker on a "Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.2 (Maipo)" according to [these instructions](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/rhel/) but `sudo yum install docker-engine` fails with:

```
https://yum.dockerproject.org/repo/main/centos/7Server/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 403 - Forbidden
```

Trying [that url](https://yum.dockerproject.org/repo/main/centos/7Server/repodata/repomd.xml) on the browser (from my local machine, which supposedly doesn't have access restrictions) actually fails in the same way. I've also noticed that if I [replace the version "7Server" by "7" in the url](https://yum.dockerproject.org/repo/main/centos/7/repodata/repomd.xml) I do get access from the browser.

What is going on there? Why is docker "7Server" inaccessible? Why does yum pick that version? Can I have it pick "7" instead? Or how can I install Docker on that RedHad distribution otherwise?

---

Note: On similar SE questions, people suggest [disabling SELinux](https://serverfault.com/questions/697752/yum-repo-responding-with-errno-14-http-error-403-forbidden) or [disabling a proxy setting](https://superuser.com/questions/767443/mirror-repository-wont-work-the-requested-url-returned-error-403-forbidden) but I believe the fact I also get 403 from the browser as described rules these off (I also can't find any proxy setting on my [`/etc/yum.conf`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22998667/errno-14-pycurl-error-22-the-requested-url-returned-error-403-forbidden) or [`/etc/yum.repos.d/*/hdp.conf`](https://superuser.com/questions/767443/mirror-repository-wont-work-the-requested-url-returned-error-403-forbidden)).

Answer (score 1):

Actually your /etc/yum.repos.d/docker.repo file should look like this

```
[dockerrepo]
name=Docker Repository
baseurl=https://yum.dockerproject.org/repo/main/centos/7/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://yum.dockerproject.org/gpg
```

It should solve your problem.